# Time complexity of a binary search matrix

Tags: c++, time-complexity, binary-search

I am having some problems in the time complexity of this function, in my opinion it's O(nlogn) because the binary search (applied in the column of the matrix) costs O(logn), whereas the first for loop costs O(n) (the number of initial rows). NB: The matrix is always n*n
Here the code

```cpp
void findMaxTreasureAux(vector<vector<int>>& map, int columns, int& index_row, int& index_column, int limitsx) {
    
    int med = columns/2;
    int max = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < map.at(0).size(); i++) {
        if (map[i][med+limitsx] > max) {
            index_row = i;
            max = map[i][med+limitsx];
        }
    }
    
    if (med+1+limitsx < map.at(0).size() && map[index_row][med+1+limitsx] > max) 
        findMaxTreasureAux(map, med, index_row, index_column, med+1);
    else if (med - 1 >= 0 && map[index_row][med-1] > max)
        findMaxTreasureAux(map, med, index_row, index_column, limitsx);
    else index_column = med+limitsx;
    
}

void findMaxTreasure(vector<vector<int>>& map, int columns, int& index_row, int& index_column) {
  
  if (map.empty()) return;
  index_column = 0;
  index_row = 0;
  findMaxTreasureAux(map, columns, index_row, index_column, 0); 
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know if the time complexity calculated by me it's correct or not. I don't know If the time complexity in this case should be O(logn)*O(n) = O(nlogn) or O(n) + O(logn) = O(n). Or maybe they are both incorrect

Comment: What does this code do? I can't tell what you're searching for.

Comment: I'm searching a number in the matrix with this features: the adjacent number(horizontally and vertically) must be lower.
example
1 2 9
0 7 4
2 6 9
in this case 7 is a good number because it's higher than 2, than 4, than 0 and than 6.

A matrix in this exercise could have more than one "good" number. I pass all the test cases, the code should work

Comment: I don't understand how you can use a binary search on this. A binary search requires some concept of ordering where you can check a property of a pivot value, and instantly eliminate half of the values. Since this matrix doesn't appear to ordered, you can't use a binary search.

Comment: This is what my code should do: I search the middle column, then of this column i search the max, found the max I compare this value to its adjacent value (the one in the left and the one in the right) If both of them are lower than this max. I save the 2 index_row and index column and end the function.
If the left value is higher I search in the left-side of the matrix, if the right value is higher I search in the right-side of the matrix

Comment: @JohnFilleau I think it works because it's really a gradient ascent in disguise (just unnecessarily complicated and doing more work than necessary). If you start from an arbitrary position and walk from that to a higher neighbor, sooner or later you'll run out of higher neighbors and reach a local maximum.

Comment: @igor okay - so they don't need to the global maxima. Just any local maxima. Nice.

Comment: What happens if you hit a "plateau"? Say, two adjacent 9's that are surrounded by 6 non-9's?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes, the OP said "the adjacent number(horizontally and vertically) must be lower,  a matrix could have more than one "good" number". I think that's a long-winded way of saying "find any local maximum".

Comment: @JohnFilleau Both of 9 are correct, so you can save one of their coordinate

Comment: But the problem here is the time complexity, essentially I'm doing a binary search in the columns, with a for loop in the rows to search the max of that column

Comment: The complexity of the code as written is indeed `O(n log n)`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that O(logn)*O(n) = O(nlogn).